# Prove the metric distance function is continuous using only topology?

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $τ$ the corresponding topology on $X$.  Fix $a∈X$.  Prove that the map $f:  (X,τ)→R$ defined by $f(x)=d(a,x)$ is continuous.

Is there a way that this can be proved using only topology without using the epsilon-delta definition?

Comment: The $\varepsilon-\delta$ method would be equivalent to any "preimage of open set" proof, since $X$ and $\mathbb{R}$ both have the metric topology.

Answer (score 0):

We can use that $\Bbb R$ is an ordered topological space as well:

Let $O=(\beta,\rightarrow)=\{r \in \Bbb R\mid r > \beta\}$ be a subbasic set in $\Bbb R$. Let $x \in f^{-1}[O]$ be arbitrary (so we know that $d(x,a) > \beta$).

Set $r=d(x,a)-\beta > 0$ and show that $B(x,r) \subseteq f^{-1}[O]$. So $f^{-1}[O]$ is open.

If $O'=(\leftarrow, \gamma)=\{r \in \Bbb R\mid r < \gamma\}$ is another type of subbasic open set, let $x \in f^{-1}[O']$ and set $r' = \gamma-d(x,a)>0$. Then show $B(x, r') \subseteq f^{-1}[O']$ so the latter set is also open.

From these two facts it follows that $f$ is continuous.